# Passing variable to jq to edit a json file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, json, jq

I am trying to pass a variable into jq like this `'.Linux.date.$var'` so far I have tried quoting them by name which is working fine. But I want to use variable to call them.

I have this, which is working fine

```
exectime=$(date -d now);    
cp $check_exec_history $check_exec_history.tmp
    jq --arg key1 true --arg key2 "$exectime" --arg name "$name" '.Linux.script_executed.first = $key1 | .Linux.date_executed.first = $key2' $check_exec_history.tmp > $check_exec_history; 
    rm $check_exec_history.tmp;
```

I want to get to this, but not working:

```
name=first;
exectime=$(date -d now);
cp $check_exec_history $check_exec_history.tmp
jq --arg key1 true --arg key2 "$exectime" --arg name "$name" ".Linux.script_executed.$name = $key1 | .Linux.date_executed.$name = $key2" $check_exec_history.tmp > $check_exec_history; 
rm $check_exec_history.tmp;
```

I came this far: using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/40027395/9496100 But I am not sure where I am doing mistake.

```
name=first;
exectime=$(date -d now);    
cp $check_exec_history $check_exec_history.tmp
    jq --arg key1 true --arg key2 "$exectime" --arg name "$name" '.Linux.script_executed.name==$name = $key1 | .Linux.date_executed.name==$name = $key2' $check_exec_history.tmp > $check_exec_history; rm $check_exec_history.tmp;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use square bracket indexing on all objects in jq, so `[$name]` works for what you're trying:

```
jq --arg key1 true --arg name "$name" '.Linux.script_executed[$name] = $key1 ...'
```

This use of square brackets is not very well documented [in the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), which makes it look like you can only use `.[xyz]`, but `["x"]` works anywhere that `.x` would have as long as it's not right at the start of an expression (that is, `.a.x` and `.a["x"]` are the same, but `["x"]` is an array construction).

Note the use of *single* quotes above - that is so Bash won't try to interpret `$name` and `$key1` as shell variables. You should keep the double quotes for `--arg name "$name"`, because that really *is* a shell variable, and it should be quoted to make it safe to use.

Comment: Had to use `-n/--null-input` two work without piped input
`name=foobar; jq -n --arg key1 true --arg name "$name" '.Linux.script_executed[$name] = $key1'`

Comment: Square bracket help me and fix my issue. Below is sample I used in my case:
RUNNER_TOKEN=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_ID | jq '.SecretString|fromjson' | jq --arg kt $SECRET_KEY -r '.[$kt]' | tr -d '"')

Answer (score -1):

Michael Homer has the correct response. I'll post what I was aiming for in relation to op's question.

I am trying to modify a permissions graph obtained through a REST API curl call using `jq` to output a json file which I will `PUT` to the server with updates. The following is the output of the curl API query:

```
{
  "revision": 2,
  "groups": {
    "1": {
      "1": {
        "native": "none",
        "schemas": "none"
      },
      "2": {
        "native": "write",
        "schemas": "all"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "1": {
        "native": "write",
        "schemas": "all"
      },
      "2": {
        "native": "write",
        "schemas": "all"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it is nested. I am trying to modify this using bash variables every time a new permission set is created and when databases are created. For exmaple I'm trying to modify `groups."1"."2"."native"` and "schemas" also `"groups."2"."2".native` and "schemas" values. It's rough, but the keys are as follows `groups.groupPermissionID.DatabaseID.*`

In order to modify this nested graph on the fly via a bash shell script, I used Michael Homer's solution of applying `[$name]`. In my case I had to do this twice in a row. i.e., `[$gID][$dID]`. In the following setup the variables are constant but in my model they are command arguments passed to the bash shell script.

```
dbID="2"
pgroupID="2"

curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Metabase-Session: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX" "http://localhost:9000/api/permissions/graph" | jq --arg dID "$dbID"   --arg gID "$pgroupID" -r '.groups."1"[$dID]."native" = "none" | .groups."1" [$dID]."schemas" = "none" | .groups[$gID][$dID]."native" ="none" .groups[$gID][$dID]."schemas" ="none"' > permissiongraph.json
```

Which produced the following updated JSON graph for me to `PUT` to my server:

```
{
  "revision": 2,
  "groups": {
    "1": {
      "1": {
        "native": "none",
        "schemas": "none"
      },
      "2": {
        "native": "none",
        "schemas": "none"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "1": {
        "native": "write",
        "schemas": "all"
      },
      "2": {
        "native": "none",
        "schemas": "none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Michael is correct when he said this is sparsely documented. I couldn't find it anywhere in the manuals. I hope this helps someone.